# Fuse.js: Exact name match

Tags: search, fuzzy-search, fuse.js

I am trying to implement an exact name match on a database.

Is there a way to get only "Smith", and not "Smithee", "Smithers", "Smithe" etc? Setting the Distance and Threshold to 0 do not do it. I can of course go through the results once they have appeared and take out the unwanted values, but it would be more efficient to do it in one take.

Answer (score 5):

*(Hopefully you're on the latest version of Fuse.js)*

If your data looks like something like this:

```js
const list = [{ name: 'Smith' } /*, etc...*/]
```

You could use [extended search](https://fusejs.io/examples.html#extended-search):

```js
const fuse = new Fuse(list, {
  keys: ['name'],
  useExtendedSearch: true
})

// Search for items that exactly match "smith"
fuse.search('=smith')
```

Comment: I discovered that I could set the Threshold to a negative number, and that would give an exact match. But I will try your suggestion. Thanks!